# I'm trying to create a makefile when I get the following errors

Tags: 12.04, kernel, compiling

I'm am trying to compile USB drivers. Here is the result of my make file attempt:

```
user@ubuntu1310:~/Downloads/Linux_Driver$ sudo make -o cp210x
make -C /lib/modules/3.11.0-12-generic/build M= modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic/arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by `arch/x86/syscalls/../include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_32.h'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [archheaders] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The makefile contents are:

```
obj-m = cp210x.o
KVERSION = $(shell uname -r)
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Please help anyone who can. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try instead:

```
obj-m = cp210x.o
KVERSION = $(shell uname -r)
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(shell pwd) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(shell pwd) clean
```

Comment: While I agree that this fixes *an* issue, I'm getting the same error after fixing that.  Any followup answers?